# Can I sum-up time?

Tags: kinematics, time

If a kinetic process takes 1 second to complete(reach a point), and that process is repeated $n$ number of times, is this formula correct $t_t$=$n\times 1$ = total time in seconds?

It's similar to a disc's rotation, if a full revolution takes 1 second, within a minute 60 revolutions is complelte hence $RPM$ = 60.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - analogous to distances, the sum of multiple durations is still a duration.

Regarding RPM, it's a matter of units. Just like you can convert between meters and kilometers by saying "some quantity in kilometers, added together 1000 times, is the same quantity expressed in meters" - which is just multiplication in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is no time delay between the repetition of the processes, Yes.

Think of an ideal hour glass (hopefully you've played with one of these arcadic time keeping devices). We have some glass designed such that in a given time interval a given amount of sand passes from the top container to the bottom.

In an ideal hour glass where the sand which passes at a constant rate (say 1 gram of sand falls down every 1 second), we have a kinetic process. Now using the numbers I just quoted, repeat the process 5 times so that 5 grams of sand have passed. It should be clear that 5 seconds have elapsed in that time period.

Maybe the example is a little circular in logic, but nonetheless hopefully enlightening.